# How to retrieve email contacts from office 365 in a Ruby on Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, contacts, office365

I want to allow users to import their email contacts from their office 365 to my web application built on RoR (3.2)

What will be the right approach?

What is the best way to setup a dev environment for this use case considering I am working on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow [this](http://dev.office.com/code-samples-detail/2142) link.

and after all set up by above link change the scope from [openid](https://outlook.office.com/mail.read)

to

```
scope =  ["openid", "profile", "https://outlook.office.com/mail.read"]
```

:)

Comment: You've got more than a link in your answer, but if that link rots, then this answer will no longer be helpful. This may theoretically answer the question, but it would be best to include the essential parts of the answer here for future users, and provide the link for reference. [Link-dominated answers](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231) can become invalid through [link rot](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot).